# Convert PS1 prompt from bash to zsh for colour customisation

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

The macOS Monterey system uses zsh shell instead of bash, and I want to convert this bash command which you'd normally store in a `.bash_profile` file

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$"
```

into a zsh command to store in a `.zshrc` file in the home directory.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to figure this out, but I thought I'd post the answer here in case someone finds this helpful. This is the zsh equivalent to the above bash prompt

```
export PS1=$'\033[36m%n\033[m@\033[32m%m:\033[33;1m%~\033[m\$'
```

Comment: `zsh` doesn't require you to identify the non-printable bits?

Comment: Appreciate you coming back and posting this.

Comment: You shouldn't export the prompt variable. `PS1=$'\033[36m%n\033[m@\033[32m%m:\033[33;1m%~\033[m\$'` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` you can use percent expansions in the prompt, which may be a bit easier to read than the terminal escape sequences:

```
PROMPT='%F{cyan}%n%f@%F{green}%m:%F{yellow}%~%f$ '
```

Here `%F` is 'start foreground color', and `%f` is 'stop color'. `%n`, `%m` and `%~` are replaced with the user name, host name, and current directory. The full set of `%` substitutions is listed in the `zshmisc` man page.

You can also use [xterm color numbers](https://www.ditig.com/256-colors-cheat-sheet) if you get tired of the small set of named colors:

```
PROMPT='%F{39}%n%f@%F{119}%m:%F{227}%~%f %F{240}[%*]%f%# '
```